# Vertex colors not working correctly in fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, vertex

I'm trying to implement some very simple lighting, and I've gotten myself into something that I can't figure out how to fix.

I calculate the color of each vertex using this vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertexpos;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 lightpos;
uniform vec3 lightcolor;
uniform vec4 received_color;

uniform mat4 translation;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec4 vertex_color;

vec4 normal = vec4(0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0);

void attenuation(out float atten, in float distance, in float range, in float a, in float b, in float c)
{
    atten = 1.0 / ( a * distance * distance + b * distance + c) * range;
}

void main()
{
    /* position stuff */

    float atten = 0.0;
    attenuation(atten, distance(lightpos, vertexpos), 20, 1.0, 0.1, 1.0);
    vec4 vlight = normalize(lightpos - vertexpos);
    float ndotl = max(0.0, dot(normal.xyz, vlight.xyz));

    vertex_color = vec4(atten * ndotl * lightcolor * received_color.xyz, 1.0);

    gl_Position = vertexpos;
}
```

In the fragment shader I simply set color equal to vertex_color

Now, as far as I know, this should calculate the color independently for each vertex, and the colors should blend together nicely. However, this is what shows up:
[image]
I'm able to tell that the varying intensity based on distance works, but I am baffled by the fact that the color only appears in the upper left corner of each square.

I need the color to be properly calculated and used for each vertex; not just one per square.

If anyone is interested, this is the code I use for rendering:
http://pastebin.com/g6xiwFwq

Comment: I feel like `lightpos` should be a uniform.

Comment: Ah, @Iggy, that made it work! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Awesome :D! Hey, also it seems weird that you're using 4D and 3D vectors for a 2D game, but I'm sure you have some good reasons.

Comment: @Iggy: Vertex attributes are always 4D technically speaking. You can write them as `float`, `vec2` or `vec3` if you want, but that's just semantics. If you only use a 2D vertex attribute pointer, for example, GL automatically assigns `z` and `w` **0.0** and **1.0** respectively.